# Find boolean intervals long at least N samples in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a pandas dataframe

```
D=pd.DataFrame(data=[1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,5.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,5.0,5.0,8.0,1.0])
```

I identify values below a certain threshold

```
a=D<4.0
```

I can count the consecutive occurences of `True` values for a condition:

```
df1 = a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

yields:

```
df1
Out[121]: 
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   0
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  1
```

Now I would like to transform `df1` to get to a dataframe that has
`True` if the number of consecutive elements meeting the condition was 3 or more, and `False` when it was 3 or less. I have tried

```
df1.loc[:,'part of interest']=df1.values>3.0
```

This leads to:

```
        0  part of interest
0   1                  False
1   2                  False
2   3                  False
3   4                   True
4   0                  False
5   1                  False
6   2                  False
7   3                  False
8   0                  False
9   0                  False
10  0                  False
11  1                  False
```

which is correct. I only need to have True values for all the elements (0,1,2,3) and not only for those where the values was above.
Desired output:

```
 0  part of interest
0   1                  **True**
1   2                  **True**
2   3                  **True**
3   4                   True
4   0                  False
5   1                  False
6   2                  False
7   3                  False
8   0                  False
9   0                  False
10  0                  False
11  1                  False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish each consecutive group first and then `map` by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), but first remove `0` values:

```
b = a.ne(a.shift()).cumsum() * a
m = b[0].map(b[0].mask(b[0] == 0).value_counts()) > 3

df1 = a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int) 
df1['part of interest'] = m
print (df1)
    0  part of interest
0   1              True
1   2              True
2   3              True
3   4              True
4   0             False
5   1             False
6   2             False
7   3             False
8   0             False
9   0             False
10  0             False
11  1             False
```

Detail:

```
print (b)
    0
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  5

print (b[0].mask(b[0] == 0).value_counts())
1.0    4
3.0    3
5.0    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64

print (b[0].map(b[0].mask(b[0] == 0).value_counts()))
0     4.0
1     4.0
2     4.0
3     4.0
4     NaN
5     3.0
6     3.0
7     3.0
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```